# Get proportionate values of columns in a dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like this,

```
        ds  0   1   2   4   5   6
0   1991Q3  nan nan nan nan 1.0 nan
1   2014Q2  1.0 3.0 nan nan 1.0 nan
2   2014Q3  1.0 nan nan 1.0 4.0 nan
3   2014Q4  nan nan nan 2.0 3.0 nan
4   2015Q1  nan 1.0 2.0 4.0 4.0 nan
```

I would like the proportions for each column 0-6 like this,

```
        ds  0        1       2       4       5       6
0   1991Q3  0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00    1.00    0.00
1   2014Q2  0.20     0.60    0.00    0.00    0.20    0.00
2   2014Q3  0.16     0.00    0.00    0.16    0.67    0.00
3   2014Q4  0.00     0.00    0.00    0.40    0.60    0.00
4   2015Q1  0.00     0.09    0.18    0.36    0.36    0.00
```

Is there a pandas way to this? Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df = df.replace(np.nan, 0)

df = df.set_index('ds')

In [3194]: df.div(df.sum(1),0).reset_index()  
Out[3194]: 
       ds    0    1    2    4    5    6
0  1991Q3 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00
1  2014Q2 0.20 0.60 0.00 0.00 0.20 0.00
2  2014Q3 0.17 0.00 0.00 0.17 0.67 0.00
3  2014Q4 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.40 0.60 0.00
4  2015Q1 0.00 0.09 0.18 0.36 0.36 0.00
```

**OR** you can use `df.apply`:

```
In [3196]: df = df.replace(np.nan, 0)
In [3197]: df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: x/x.sum(), axis=1)
In [3198]: df
Out[3197]: 
       ds    0    1    2    4    5    6
0  1991Q3 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 1.00 0.00
1  2014Q2 0.20 0.60 0.00 0.00 0.20 0.00
2  2014Q3 0.17 0.00 0.00 0.17 0.67 0.00
3  2014Q4 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.40 0.60 0.00
4  2015Q1 0.00 0.09 0.18 0.36 0.36 0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the first column as the index, get the sum of each row, and divide the main dataframe by the sums, and filling the null entries with 0

```
res = df.set_index("ds")


res.fillna(0).div(res.sum(1),axis=0)
```

Comment: I am getting an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Period' and 'float'`